# how to show notifications in outook addin

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages is supported only requirement version 1.3 or later, if I want to show notifications in old versions of outlook. what is the best way of doing?

Comment: I also need to show loading indicator for some api calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a message as well as the loading indicator in the add-in's UI, and in this case, the task pane.

Comment: yeah I have incorporated office UI frabric js for messages[https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/MessageBar/MessageBar.html] and spinner[https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Spinner/Spinner.html] looks very neat. thank you.